# How to add typehint in sphinx for property with getter

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-typing

I'm using sphinx for generating "automated" documentation from doc-strings and type hints. However I'm struggling to show (in the generated documentation) type of a property with a getter.

---

In case of simple properties I get the desired documentation:

```
class Cls:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop: int = 42
```

will generate this (desired) documentation:

**prop**: *int*

---

In case of a method we will get similarly useful result:

```
class Cls:
    def mth(self) -> int:
        return 42
```

**mth**() → *int*

---

However if we want to use getter (`@property` decorator) I can't manage to get the type there:

```
class Cls:
    @property
    def prop(self) -> int:
        return 42
```

*property* **prop**

Notice there is no type hint

---

Do you know how to add the type hint into the documentation in the last case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in sphinx 4. See [this PR](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/8983) and [this issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7383).

<s>Sphinx 4 is not released yet, but there already is the [4.0.0b1 pre-release](https://pypi.org/project/Sphinx/#history)</s> (released now) which produces:

```py
class Cls:
    @property
    def prop(self) -> int:
        return 42
```

*property* **prop**: *int*

You can maybe just use this pre-release if it doesn't break anything for you.